# All products are discounted

Tags: products, discount

I added a **discount code** and noticed **all products** were applied by the **discount**, so removed and deleted.

However all  **products are still discounted**. No codes are active, **all deleted**. HELP !!!!

Comment: Check if there is any catalog price rules are active or not and also try reindex.

Comment: Which version of Magento are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

this could be reindex issue

go to your magento root in cli

```
cd /yourMagentoRoot/

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

and check after that